# Transmute over multiple columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dplyr question: How do I use `transmute` over each column without writing each column out by hand? I.e. is there something like `transmute_each()`?

I want to do the following: Using dplyr I want to get the z-score of each column for a MWE below:

```
tickers <- c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10))
df <- data.frame(cbind(tickers,rep(1:20),rep(2:21),rep(2:21),rep(4:23),rep(3:22)))
colnames(df) <- c("tickers","col1","col2","col3","col4","col5")
df %>%  group_by(tickers)
```

Is there a simple way to then use transmute to achieve the following:

```
for(i in 2:ncol(df)){
  df[,i] <- df[,i] - mean(df[,i])/sd(df[,i])
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Just use `mutate_each` and drop the unwanted columns afterward.

Comment: Thanks @Hongooi, what I set out to do initially, but would have liked to have a transmute_each type wrapper as well.

Comment: AFAIK, there's currently no `transmute_each` function in dplyr, but you could define it yourself, for example using `transmute_each <- function(tbl, funs, ...) {mutate_each(tbl, funs, ...) %>% select(...)}`

Answer (score 6):

Now that there is a `transmute_at()` function (as of dplyr 0.7), you can do the following:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(tickers) %>% 
    transmute_at(.vars = vars(starts_with("col")),
                 .funs = funs(scale(.))) %>% 
    ungroup
```

Note that this uses the `scale()` function from base R, which by default converts a numeric vector into a z-score.

Also, the use of `vars()` in the `.vars` argument allows you to use all the helper functions that are available for dplyr's `select()`, such as `one_of()`, `ends_with()`, etc.

Finally, instead of writing `funs(scale(.))` here, since you're using a simple function in the `.funs` argument, you can just write `.funs = scale`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using the following:

```
df %>%  
   group_by(tickers) %>%  
   mutate_at(.funs = funs((. - mean(.))/sd(.)),
             .cols = vars(matches("col")))
```

Comment: Note that this is not a particularly good use case for a hypothetical `transmute_each` function because _all_ columns (except the grouping column, which cannot be dropped) fulfill your selection criteria (`matches("col")`). That means, in this case `transmute_each` would do the same as `mutate_each`.